# record not inserting into access database

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I have a C# windows application and I’m trying to insert data (which has been entered by the user) into an access database.  I am not getting any errors, however it is not entering the data.  Any thought?

```
        string sqlInsert = "insert into assessment (id) values (@id)";

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(dsn))
        {

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlInsert, conn);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = iDTextBox.Text.Trim().Length != null ? storedID.Trim() : "";

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

The datatype for id is `Text`.

Edit:
connection string is stored in app.config as:

```
<add name="conn" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\CADSCUPP.mdb" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>
```

and accessed in the code by:

```
private string dsn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
```

If I insert records manually (not through the code behind code) I can read the records elsewhere in the program so that connection works.

Comment: OleDbType.VarChar? Isn't the ID is a number?

Comment: How do you know that the record is not being written? Are you querying the database from ASP.NET, or looking at the table in Access to verify it?  You might check that ASP.NET and VS haven't made a copy of the database somewhere else on your development machine.  I don't know that that happens with ASP.NET, but I've seen it happen with WinForms apps on Win7 that use Access dbs.

Comment: As a matter of curiosity, does that query work as expected in MS Access?

Comment: @AnnL. luckily there are no copies being generated. I know its written from both .net and access

Comment: @Remou yes, the query works as expected in access

Comment: @peroija  Out of curiosity, have you looked at the value returned by ExecuteNonQuery()? That should indicate how many records (if any) were affected. Also, what kind of error trapping/handling are you doing?

Comment: @AnnL. 1 is returned. no error trapping/handling because I was hoping for some error to show up. It acts like in the moment it added a row but when the app is done there is nothing in there.

Comment: Try forcing an error, just to see what happens:  change your `sqlInsert` to insert to a field or table that doesn't exist.  See if an error is thrown.  Also try inserting into a different table and see if the problem is still there across all tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7 has been known to make copies of Access databases in other places, when compiling and running WinForms apps.  I don't know that it does this with ASP.NET apps, but it's a possibility.  It might be worth verifying that the database being accessed by the app is in the location you think it is.

Comment: turns out a few folders in under debug it was re-creating the database and saving it there

Comment: Yes it copies it inside bin folder where executable resides. and on every build it replaces it with the copy which in in your solution's folder. So you can see your data if you don't build and execute your exe file.

Answer (score 1):

Use question marks instead of @ in Sql Text. Parameter names don't matter with access. Only the order counts. I have not used access in quite some time-- but that is one thing that I remember, it used to drive me crazy. With Access the parameter names don't matter.

```
string sqlInsert = "insert into assessment (id) values (?)";

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(dsn))
        {

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlInsert, conn);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = iDTextBox.Text.Trim().Length == 0 ? storedID.Trim() : "";

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: @peroija - see my updates-- what does the table assessment look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can verify that your string connection is correct

Sample :

```
connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=yourdatabasename.mdb;"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any authentication in your connection string. Try out one of these strings:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing to mention command type. Add another line like following:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlInsert, conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```